# Understanding open balls in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x_0 \in X$ and $r>0$ a real number.

The open ball in X of radius r centred on $x_0$ is the set

$B_r (x_0)=\{x \in X : d(x,x_0) <r \}$

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d=d_2$ the Euclidean metric. Then $B_r (x_0)$ is the set of all points strictly inside the circle of radius r centred on $x_0$.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d=d_1$. Then $B_r (x_0)$ is the inside of a square centred on $x_0$ with diagonals of length 2r parallel to the axes.

What I do not understand is what does $d=d_2$ and $d=d_1$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you use $d_2$ for the metric and in the second $d_1$. I guess $d_p$ shall be the metric induced by the [p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions):

$$d_p(x,y) = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^p} $$

So:

$$d_2(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^2} $$

and

$$d_1(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i| $$